# Ubuntu Server mod_chroot Apache2 Problem

Tags: apache-2.2, chroot

I am trying to make it so my apache web pages will be in a chroot jail. I have set up my chroot jail as according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ModChroot. However when i restart apache i get the following error logged:

[error] No such file or directory: could not create /var/chroot/apache/var/run/apache2.pid
[error] apache2: could not log pid to file /var/chroot/apache/var/run/apache2.pid

/var/chroot/apache/var/run/apache2.pid is there with 777 permissions

If i dissable mod_chroot web pages are delivered correctly from the /var/chroot/apache/var/www directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that Apache is trying to write the PID file *after* it's done the chroot - i.e. when Apache think's it's trying to write to **/var/chroot/apache/var/run/apache2.pid**, it's actually trying to write to **/var/chroot/apache/var/chroot/apache/var/run/apache2.pid**

Check the Apache config files to see what PidFile is set to - it probably should be just

```
PidFile /var/run/apache2.pid
```

See http://core.segfault.pl/~hobbit/mod_chroot/apache20.html for other config tweaks you may need to do to use mod_chroot with Apache 2.x